# Snakemake : multi-level json parsing

Tags: json, merge, snakemake

I've a json configuration file that looks like:

```
{
    "projet_name": "Project 1",
    "samples": [
        {
        "sample_name": "Sample_A",
        "files":[
            {
                "a": "file_A_a1.txt",
                "b": "file_A_a2.txt",
                "x": "x1"
            },
            {
                "a": "file_A_b1.txt",
                "b": "file_A_b2.txt",
                "x": "x1"
            },
            {
                "a": "file_A_c1.txt",
                "b": "file_A_c2.txt",
                "x": "x2"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
        "sample_name": "Sample_B",
        "files":[
            {
                "a": "file_B_a1.txt",
                "b": "file_B_a2.txt",
                "x": "x1"
            },
            {
                "a": "file_B_b1.txt",
                "b": "file_B_b2.txt",
                "x": "x1"
            }
            ]
        }]
}
```

I'm currently writing a snakemake file to process such json file. The idea is to for each sample (e.g. Sample_A , Sample_B) to concatenate the files that have the same "x" entry. For example in Sample_A, I would like to concatenate "a" files : file_A_a1.txt and file_A_b1.txt as they have the same "x" entry. Same for "b" files : file_A_a2.txt and file_A_b2.txt. file_A_c1.txt and file_A_c2.txt will not be concatenate with other files as they have a unique "x". At the end I would like a structure like this :

```
merged_files/Sample_A_a_x1.txt
merged_files/Sample_A_b_x1.txt
merged_files/Sample_A_a_x2.txt
merged_files/Sample_A_b_x2.txt
merged_files/Sample_B_a_x1.txt
merged_files/Sample_B_b_x1.txt
```

My issue is the grouping of files with same "sample_name" and same "x" .. Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, 

Snakemake allows to use python's combinatorial functions like `zip`, see in documentation: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html#targets

Also, `json` format is not always easy to handle, and snakemake allows to use `yaml` files. You could also store sample information in a tab-delimited file which path could be in the configuration file.

Comment: Indeed. See here for a good example for using separate sample sheets: https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/rna-seq-star-deseq2

Comment: Thank you. I'll go for a separate samplesheet as you suggest.

Comment: In fact I'm really struggling with the logic behind your script. I'm still a snakmake newbie.. could you explain the get_fastq function :

`def get_fastq(wildcards):
    return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), ["fq1","fq2"]].dropna()`